# How to migrate from regular bootstrap to ui-bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I started writing an angular application using regular [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). Then I came across [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). I already had some HTML mostly taken from examples from the bootstrap page customized a little. Actually working okay, but apparently [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) is the way to go in conjunction with angular.

What I don't understand is how do I migrate my HTML from here? The drop-down navigation for example isn't working anymore. Do I have to exchange the data-* attributes through the [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) directives? Or do I have to change the classes like in the [migration guide](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/Migration-guide-for-prefixes)? I know, that the migration guid has nothing to do with migrating from [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). But the old names from [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) seem to match the classes of [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

I'm new to angular and bootstrap so I'm a little confused here, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your goal is. ui-bootstrap is an angular-style replacement for the bootstrap javascript. It doesn't depend on jQuery so that can reduce your footprint dramatically if you don't need jQuery for other purposes.

If your goal is to remove Bootstrap.js, then you would need to replace the data-attributes with ui-bootstrap directives.

Vanilla Bootstrap works pretty well with angular too.

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by footprint? My goal is not to remove bootstrap.js, but to make things work out smoothly, i.e. without any conflict and most importantly to use the $uibModal service. Unfortunately just exchanging the data-* attributes with the corresponding directives didn't work. I'll see if I can come up with a plunkr to make things clearer.

Comment: I got it to work. It's a little fiddly to migrate the bootstrap examples, because ui-bootstrap uses more directives than bootstrap uses data-* attributes. So you need to look a little more in detail, compare the examples and add all directives.

Comment: With footprint I mean download size. ui.bootstrap has no external dependencies whereas bootstrap.js depends on jquery.